# Python mysql connector returns tuple

Tags: python, mysql-connector

I am connecting to mysql database via mysql connector and running a simple query to pull a list of IDs. I need to loop over that list and pass them into some other code. For some reason I am getting a list of tuples. Is this expected behavior? If not, what am I doing wrong?
Here is the snippet of my code:

```
import mysql.connector
conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='127.0.0.1', database='t', user='r', password='pwd')
cursor = conn.cursor()
query = ( "select id from T where updated < '%s'" % (run_date) )
cursor.execute(query)
for row in cursor:
   print (row)

cursor.close()
```

I am getting the following back (from an INT field in d/b):

```
(Decimal('991837'),)
(Decimal('991838'),)
(Decimal('991839'),)
(Decimal('991871'),)
(Decimal('991879'),)
(Decimal('991899'),)
(Decimal('992051'),)
(Decimal('992299'),)
(Decimal('992309'),)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behavior. Using the cursor as an iterable is basically equivalent to looping over it using the `fetchone()` method. From the [documentation for `fetchone()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchone.html) (emphasis mine):

> This method retrieves the next row of a query result set and returns a
>   single **sequence**, or None if no more rows are available. By default,
>   **the returned tuple** consists of data returned by the MySQL server,
>   converted to Python objects. If the cursor is a raw cursor, no such
>   conversion occurs;

Comment: Not really related to the original question I asked, but how to I convert (Decimal('992309'),) to 992309 ?

Comment: @epipko Grab the first element of the tuple (`[0]`), then you've got a [Decimal object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal-objects) which you can convert to `int` if you need to.

Answer (score 5):

if you want to access just the data in the row you need to go into the dictionary

first you must make it true in the cursor

```py
cur = db.cursor( buffered=True , dictionary=True)
```

then the result will be like this :

```py
{'Decimal' : '991837'}
```

i'm sure the Decimal is your row name 
so when you need to access to the value do this

```py
import mysql.connector
conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='127.0.0.1', database='t', user='r', password='pwd')
cursor = conn.cursor()
query = ( "select id from T where updated < '%s'" % (run_date) )
cursor.execute(query)
for row in cursor:
   print (row['Decimal'])

cursor.close()
```

i hope it works for i was looking for this solution for the past 2 days and no answers
the only way i debugged i opened the debugger and print out all the variables
have fun with Python :)